# Pointer value of *x &x and x

Tags: c, pointers

suppose this code:

```
main()
{
    int *x;
    *x = 3;

    printf("%d %d %d\n", *x, &x, x);
    // output 3 5448392 2293524
}
```

if `*x` is the value; `&x` the addres; what does mean that value of `x`?

Comment: Note, you are accessing random memory with your `*x = 3` as `x` is not initialized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Adr     value    expression
----------------------------------------------
5448392 2293524  &x address of x
2293524 3         x place where you assigned 3
```

Comment: @Fabricio No, there is an adress where the value (3 in the question) is stored and the pointer itself needs also a place in memory to store the address of the value it is pointing to.

Answer (score 9):

- `*x` is the value (correct)
- `x` is the address of the value. **EDIT** In your case, this address is uninitialized, so it is not pointing anywhere in particular (thanks Keith Nicholas for mentioning this).
- `&x` is the address of the [pointer that *should* contain the] address of the value.

(it's worth pointing out that your program may crash :)

Comment: last one is wrong,  its the address of the pointer containing the address of the value.

Comment: second one is wrong also,  it is a pointer  ( which can contain an address of an int)  and in his case it is uninitialized

Answer (score 3):

`x` gives you the address in memory where value of `*x`, i.e. `3` is located. `&x` gives the address where value of `x`, i.e. `2293524` is located.

Comment: x is not an address, its a pointer that contains the address...  the difference is where a LOT of people get mucked up by pointers and addresses of locations.

Comment: @KeithNicholas: Thanks. I do understand the difference, just used wrong words. Is it better now? :)

Comment: yeah, i figured, once you know, its easy to shortcut the way you say things,  I just know from trying to explain it to people who have never come across pointers that they get all mucked up

Answer (score 2):

It is the address that x contains. Having been declared as a pointer, x stores an address, while &x is in a sense a pointer to a pointer.

EDIT: So I wasn't as precise as perhaps I should have been. &x is strictly speaking not a pointer to a pointer. It is the address of a pointer. In the following line of code, y is a pointer to a pointer:

```
int **y = &x;
```

Comment: Did you mean "the address that contains x" ?

Comment: &x is not a pointer to a pointer.... very important as people get mucked up this,  its just the address of the pointer,  to make a pointer to a pointer you need to allocate/declare a pointer that you then put the address of the pointer into.

Comment: @paxdiablo No. I mean pretty much what I wrote. x is a pointer, so its value is an address. &x is the address of the memory containing x's value.

Comment: I have to disagree on your phrasing. The "address that `x` contains" is it's _value,_ `*x`. That's because `x` is a pointer, and it "contains" `*x`. The "address that contains `x`" (`&x`) is its address.

Comment: @paxdiablo: If I declare `int w = 4;` and `int *x = 0xFEEDBEEF;`, then `w` contains an integer and `x` contains an address. `&w` is an address to the integer value that `w` contains (4) and `&x` is an address to the address value that `x` contains (0xFEEDBEEF). We may have to agree to disagree. :)

Answer (score 2):

x is a pointer to an int,   its not an int itself, its not the address of an int, its a pointer.

a pointer contains an address of an int.

so, a missing step you have  ( your program doesn't point x to anything! very dangerous)

```
int y = 5;
int *x;

x = &y     // put the memory location of y into the pointer
```

if you now print the contents of the pointer...

```
printf("%d\n", x);    // prints out the memory location of y;
```

now to get to the value of what your pointer points to ( at the moment, y)

```
printf("%p\n", *x);    // prints out 5;
```

now, just like y has a memory location,   x also has a location in memory

so  &x   is where the pointer 'x' is in memory

Comment: `d` conversion specifier with an argument of a pointer type is undefined behavior.

Comment: Specifically, you should use `%p` to print pointer values, and cast the argument to `(void *)`: `printf("%p\n", (void *) x);`.

Answer (score 1):

`x` is uninitialized so it points to nowhere and dereferencing it with `*` is undefined behaviour.

The following would be a more correct (and useful) program

```
main()
{
    int x;   //declare an int variable
    int *xp; //declare a pointer to an int variable
    xp = &x;
    *xp = 3;

    printf("%d %d %d %d %d\n", x, &x, xp, *xp, &xp);
}
```

x is a value, xp and &xp point to that value, *xp can be used to access and change the value and &xp is a pointer to that pointer...

Comment: `d` conversion specifier with an argument of a pointer type is undefined behavior.

Comment: @ouah: I assumed it was not the best but kept it to avoid changing *too* much. Do you know any platform where this is an issue?

Answer (score 1):

`&x` is the address of the **pointer** object.
The value of the pointer is the address of an `int`.

Also, you shouldn't assign to *x as in your example: `x` doesn't point anywhere valid.

Answer (score 1):

`x` and `&x` values are of pointer types so you should use `p` conversion specifier to print their values.

```
printf("%d %p %p\n", *x, (void *) &x, (void *) x);
```

Don't forget to cast to `void *` otherwise the call to `printf`is undefined behavior. (`p` conversion specifier requires an argument of type `void *`).

```
int *x;
int y = 0;      
x = &y; 
*x = 3;
```

`x` is a pointer to `int`. `*x` is an `int` and its value is 3. And `&x` is a pointer to a pointer to `int`. Note that your pointer has to point to a valid object object (like above) otherwise it has an invalid value.